# Convert an particular TD element of a table to Select with pre-populated Options

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am very new to jQuery,so bear with me if it seems to be silly question.
I have an table with many TD's in each row.I need to **convert an TD element with plain text** belonging to a particular column **into an TD with Select element** with pre-populated options,**when user clicks that TD** of that column using jQuery.

Comment: You could append the HTML code to that TD?

Answer (score 1):

You can't *convert* the `td` into a `select`, because that would result in an invalid document. What you can do, is put the `select` *within* the `td`. E.g.:

```
$('selector for the td in question').html(
    '<select>' +
    '<option value="1">One</option>' +
    '<option value="2">Two</option>' +
    '<option value="3">Three</option>' +
    '</select>'
);
```

Here's a complete example, also demonstrating event delegation: [Live Copy](http://jsbin.com/dutonofe/2)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>Select in Cell</title>
  <style>
    .type {
      cursor: pointer;
      white-space: nowrap;
    }
    table {
      border: 1px solid #aaa;
      border-collapse: collapse;
    }
    td, th {
      border: 1px solid #aaa;
      padding: 2px;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <p>Click cells in the type column.</p>
  <table id="theTable">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Type</th>
        <th>Description</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td class="type">Thingy</td>
        <td>Blah</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="type">Widget</td>
        <td>Blah</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="type">Whatsit</td>
        <td>Blah</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <script>
    (function() {
      $("#theTable").on("click", ".type", function() {
        var $this = $(this),
            current = $this.text(),
            select;
        if ($this.find("select").length) {
          return;
        }
        select = $(
          '<select>' +
          '<option>Thingy</option>' +
          '<option>Widget</option>' +
          '<option>Whatsit</option>' +
          '</select>'
        );
        $this.html(select);
        select.val(current).focus();
      });
      $("#theTable").on("blur", ".type select", function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.closest('td').text($this.val());
      });
    })();
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks!
But the dropdown list in your demo doesn't allows to select an option.

Comment: @HiteshJain: Does for me, using Chrome. (What are you using?) You might want to not use `blur` to get rid of it, if that's causing some cross-browser issue. Just add an "OK" button next to it or similar.

Comment: @HiteshJain: Eww, IE8 really doesn't like it, you're right.

Comment: @HiteshJain: It was me being silly: The `click` event bubbles, so subsequent clicks (on the `select`) were going up to the `td` and being handled again. Fixed it.

Comment: using your code,if the 'TD' element is selected but no option from select dropdown is selected by user,then it shows null...how to make it the previous value in textbox,if nothing from dropdown is selected

Comment: @HiteshJain: Store the information (probably using `data`) and use it if you find no selected options.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting task. Try this solution:

```
$('table').on('click', 'td', function(e) {

    if ($(this).data('converted')) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        return;
    }

    $(this).data('converted', $(this).text());

    var rowIndex = this.parentNode.rowIndex,
        index = this.cellIndex + 1,
        options = $(e.delegateTarget).find('td:nth-child(' + index +')').map(function(i) {
            var text = $(this).data('converted') || $(this).text();
            return '<option ' + (rowIndex == i ? 'selected' : '')  + '>' + text + '</option>';
        }).get();

    $(this).html('<select>' + options.join('') + '</select>');
});
```

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/As9dY/2/

Comment: You can accept this answer if it's what you needed.

Answer (score 0):

Q: How to add a select dropdown to a TD dynamically?

Here's how you do it:

**HTML:**

```
<table>
    <tr><th>Column A</th><th>Column B</th></tr>
    <tr><td>1</td><td>6</td></tr>
    <tr><td>2</td><td>7</td></tr>
    <tr><td>3</td><td>8</td></tr>
    <tr><td>4</td><td id="nine">9</td></tr>
    <tr><td>5</td><td>10</td></tr>    
</table>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 var isAppended = false;
 var select = "<select name='mySelect'>" +
             "<option value='volvo'>Volvo</option>" +
             "<option value='saab'>Saab</option>" +
             "<option value='opel'>Opel</option>" +
             "<option value='audi'>Audi</option>" +
             "</select>";


 $("#nine").click(function() {
     if (!isAppended) {
        $(this).append(select);  
         isAppended = true;
     }    
 });

});
```

**[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/c3d8Y/1/)**

Comment: thanks,i was looking for this only,but the demo that u have given link to appends a new select on every click.What i need is,select should be appeneded only once.

Comment: I have updated my code. Try now with this simple hack ;)

Comment: thanks,but there are is an entire column that needs to be converted to select whenever user onclick's,however your code converts only an particular TD element.